# Eventhandling in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am writing an Angular application that can show and edit a list of records. I have learned that calling subscribe manually is always a bad thing because then I would have to unsubscibe manually as well (I usually forget that). A better way of doing it is, to use the async Pipe.

So I am trying rewrite my code, but I can't wrap my head around it. Here is what I do:

```
this.dataSource = this.route.params
    .pipe(
        map(params => createFilter(params)),
        switchMap(filter => this.service.find(filter)));
```

in the HTML I then use `*ngFor="let item of dataSource | async"`

That is clean, I suppose. Now I tried to encorporate a searchfield to further enhance my filtering capabilities.

```
this.dataSource = combineLatest({
    params: this.route.params, 
    search: this.searchFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''))
})
    .pipe(
        map(o => Object.assign(o, { filter: createFilter(params) })),
        switchMap(o => this.service.find(o.filter, o.search)));
```

That looks quite ugly, but it still feels kind of clean.
There is one more thing I'd like to do and that is to programmatically refresh. For instance after saving a new record I'd like to refresh my list of records, so it includes the new one as well.
How can I do that, and is it really what I should do?

Comment: It's doable for the refresh, just add the stream of the new record to the combineLatest with a startWith null. But I think you're reaching a point where it might be a good idea considering using a state management library (I do use ngrx a lot but there are plenty of others out there if you prefer)

Comment: While several people want to ignore the question I think this can be made to work well reactively using events (either with angular's version and a BehaviorSubject or with fromEvent with viewChildren) and the async pipe. You could also manually subscribe, but the question makes it clear that is not desired.

Comment: @Mr.H. I wrote an answer before realizing you wanted complete programmatic control. This is my bad for not reading carefully enough, but you might consider changing the name of the question. You aren't actually dealing with event handling in the traditional sense. Maybe something like "Programmatically triggering a combined Observable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find it simpler to define your observable sources separately, like this:

```js
private search$ = this.searchFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''));
private filter$ = this.route.params.pipe(map(params => createFilter(params));

dataSource = combineLatest([this.filter$, this.search$]).pipe(
    switchMap(([filter, search]) => this.service.find(filter, search))
);
```

To implement a refresh, you could use a `BehaviorSubject` as a trigger and just call its `next()` method whenever you want to refresh:

```js
private refresh$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined);
private search$ = this.searchFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''));
private filter$ = this.route.params.pipe(map(params => createFilter(params));

dataSource = combineLatest([this.filter$, this.search$, this.refresh$]).pipe(
    switchMap(([filter, search]) => this.service.find(filter, search))
);
```

Comment: Certainly, a fine way to do this but it should probably be mentioned that you will need to clean up the BehaviorSubject in the OnDestroy to avoid potential memory leaks. Since this is the reason that people generally advise against subscribing manually in the first place it is a slight con. That said this is usually how I solve problems like this in reality.

Comment: Unless there is an explicit subscription to the `BehaviorSubject`, I don't see the risk of causing memory leaks.  Can you explain further?

Comment: You are right. I don't know why I thought you needed this. You made me doubt myself, then I tried it and I can't make this leak the way I thought could.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add another member to your `combineLatest` that triggers the pipe when that event happens. You have some options in this regard. You could:

- Use a viewChild to get the manually refresh element and the rxjs operator [fromEvent](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent) to get an observable event handler. This way your subscription can be handled in the rxjs pipe (and then through the async angular pipe). This couples you to the DOM in unpleasant ways but works with the angular async pipe (this is what I would do if manual destruction is intolerable). example where the triggering event is a click on a button but it could be a form submit or anything else): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q12olm?file=src/main.ts
- (Note @BizzyBob beat me to this answer, leaving it because I have a full example but you should just refer to his for a more compact solution) Have a BehaviorSubject that you manually call programmatically or on an event. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mu4qxo?file=src/main.ts